# Nullable primitives with Generics

Tags: c#, generics, resharper, nullable

I'm trying to find the right thing to do with a non-null validation on a nullable boolean. I also want to be able to do the same thing with some other fields, including strings, ints, etc., so I want to use generics for the method. Here's an example of the kind of thing which can happen.

```
bool? myValue = null;
bool valid = ValidateNotNull(myValue);
```

And here's some validation code:

```
public bool ValidateNotNull<T>(T nullableField)
{
    return nullableField != null;
}
```

All the answers I've found to this kind of problem suggest adding a `where T : struct` or `where T: class` to the method signature, or using `default(T)` in the comparison, none of which will work for a bool where `false` is a valid value.

Any other suggestions? The code compiles, but Resharper isn't happy about that null comparison on a value which it thinks might be a primitive, and I'd love to know what I should be doing to cheer it up.

NB: This isn't the complete code. I'm still interested in maintaining the type. This is also not the only place I've run into the problem.

NB2: Yes, it compiles and works fine. What I really want to know is whether there is a code solution for stopping Resharper from complaining, or an idiomatic way to do this which I don't know about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Would comparing to default work?</s>

```
    public bool ValidateNotNull<T>(T nullableField)
    {
        return Equals(nullableField, default(T));
    }
```

**Updated:**

Either its a [primitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx), and all is well, or its not null:

```
    public bool ValidateNotNull<T>(T nullableField)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsPrimitive || !Equals(nullableField, null);
    }
```

Comment: No, because some of the fields I'm passing in might be 0 or false, which are valid. It's only null which is invalid.

Comment: Your update is incorrect. The first part is returning `true` if `T` is a value type. `System.Nullable<>` is a value type, so `bool? bar = null` would be evaluated by your method to be not null.

Comment: Dunno whether this was your original answer but I thought I'd give it a go, and it works - unit testing rocks. False and default(bool?) are not the same. Thank you! This solves my problem and I learnt a little more about C#! (And it does work - bool? bar = null does evaluate to null.)

Comment: You are right.. so I changed the code to IsPrimitive.. That should do the trick!

Comment: Either way, the Type class holds the answer :)

Comment: It works without the IsPrimitive I think. I'm not actually worried about primitives being passed in, since I'll only be validating fields which are nullable anyway - but I was worried about default(T) being false for bool? which was nonsense on my part. This is exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: Just for clarity in case anyone else finds this, the comparison I'm making in the question was `== default(T)` which definitely doesn't compile. Arcturus, your first example works fine for me, and I imagine the second will be useful in other situations. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6):

The code below will validate nullable types and reference types:

```
 public bool ValidateNotNull<T>(Nullable<T> nullableField) where T:struct
 {
  return nullableField.HasValue;
 }

 public bool ValidateNotNull<T>(T nullableField) where T:class
 {
  return nullableField!=null;
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't compile for bool? though.

Comment: Ah, you're right - I didn't spot that they were actually different implementations as well as different signatures. I prefer just having one method, but this is also beautiful so have an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

> I also want to be able to do the same thing with some other fields, including strings, ints, etc

OK, so you want a method that can be passed either a `Nullable<>` (which is a `struct`), or a reference type, and will return `true` iff the argument is `null` (note that your name appears to be the wrong way round, but there you go).

The thing is, if that's *all* this method has to do, then you don't need generics because you don't need type-safety. This example works and does what you want, I think:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int? x = null;
        int? y = 5;
        string s = null;
        string r = "moo";

        Console.WriteLine(ValidateNotNull(x));
        Console.WriteLine(ValidateNotNull(y));
        Console.WriteLine(ValidateNotNull(s));
        Console.WriteLine(ValidateNotNull(r));

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static bool ValidateNotNull(object o)
    {
        return o == null;
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
True
False
True
False
```

which is I believe your required output.

Comment: Hm, okay - I actually use the fact that it's a boolean elsewhere; this isn't the complete code, nor is it the only time I've run into this problem. I'm still looking for a way to maintain the type without having to cast. Thanks for the note on the != (copying and pasting from code which does some slightly different stuff!)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you thing your method doesn't work (apart from using `!=` rather than `==`), because as far as I can tell, it already works! You can compare any value of type T with null (when T is a generic type parameter). If a non-nullable value type is used for T, the result will be treated as a constant (`false` for `== null`, `true` for `!= null`).

So, this should be fine.

```
public bool ValidateNotNull<T>(T nullableField)
{
    return nullableField != null;
}
```

But this would also work without generics:

```
public bool ValidateNotNull(object nullableField)
{
    return nullableField != null;
}
```

(Because boxing a `Nullable<T>` null value returns a null reference.)

Comment: Like I said, it compiles and works fine - but Resharper complains.

Comment: In that case, use the second solution (with object, not T)

Answer (score -2):

You need to use

```
public bool ValidateNotNull<T>(T nullableField)
{
    return nullableField.HasValue;
}
```